# Получение значений переданных методом POST в Go

Tags: http, post, golang

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в Go собрать все значения, переданные программе методом POST?

Примерно такой код:

```
package main
import "net/http"
func main() {
     http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
     http.ListenAndServe(":80", nil)
}
func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
     if r.Method == "POST" {
           // Как собрать все значения POST ???
     }
     *****
}
```

Вариант `r.FormValue("FIELD_NAME")`, к сожалению, не подходит, поскольку мне заранее неизвестно, какие именно поля будут переданы.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

С http в Go не работал, но [в официальных](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request) доках в описании структуры `Request` есть поле `Form` типа `url.Values`, которое становится доступным после [`ParseForm`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.ParseForm).

Кароче делай `ParseForm`, а потом цикл `for` по `r.Form`.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!! 
Все получилось! 
Блин, теперь чувствую себя полным критином, яж приведенную вами страничку сто раз перечитывал ;)
Надо на будущее быть внимательней, и подтянуть наконец, до приемлемого уровня, английский! :)

Answer (score 5):

У объекта `http.Request` есть поле Form (r.Form). Это словарь всех значений. Он инициализируется после первого вызова `r.FormValue`. Вот сама ф-я `r.FormValue`

```
func (r *Request) FormValue(key string) string {
    if r.Form == nil {
        r.ParseMultipartForm(defaultMaxMemory)
    }
    if vs := r.Form[key]; len(vs) > 0 {
        return vs[0]
    }
    return ""
}
```

Чтобы получить все значения можно попробовать самому парсить запрос, а можно вызвать `r.FormValue` с пустым значением (`r.FormValue("")`). После этого у нас будет готовый словарь параметров в `r.Form`.

Answer (score 0):

```
r.FormValue("<name>")
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]