# Как в Golang получить значения POST/GET параметров?

Tags: golang

Как в *Golang* получить значения `POST/GET` параметров?

P.S. на официальном сайте был

Тут [упоминали](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/134395/), но не написали, как именно делать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Разобрался
r.FormValue("FIELD_NAME")  , где r-Request
```

Answer (score 1):

```
func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
     if r.Method == "POST" {
           r.ParseForm()
           // они все тут
           params := r.Form
     }
}
```

Пока не сделаешь r.ParseForm(), r.Form может быть пустым.

И еще

```
type Request struct {
    ...
    // Тут данные из query, url, и post - все вместе.
    // Пусто пока не вызовешь ParseForm()
    Form url.Values

    // Содержит данный форм из POST, PATCH или PUT.
    // Пусто пока не вызовешь ParseForm()
    PostForm url.Values

    // Содержит multipart form, включая загрузку файлов.
    // Пусто пока не вызовешь MultipartForm()
    MultipartForm *multipart.Form
    ...
}
```

где

```
type url.Values map[string][]string
```